# iOS: show same "Please sign-in" screen for some view controllers, then change it to real content?

Tags: ios, authorization

I have an app with tabbed view:  **search** | **subscribes** | **messages**

All tab buttons are visible at app start even for unauthorized user.

But when unauthorized user clicks on let's say **messages** tab, I want to show "MessagesViewController" but it must show grey screen:

> Please sign-in. [button sign-in] [button registration]

When user clicks [button sign-in] - modal UIViewController appears. After sign-in user goes back to "MessagesViewController" tab, but this time user can see his messages. Same grey screen must be in **subscribes** tab.

I'm new to iOS so I want to know what is a proper way to do this. Subscribes and messages are table views. Do I need to place another view on top of tables to overlap them and then hide it after authorization? Or can I create one separate "unauthorized" controller, connect it with tabs and reuse it? If so, how can I connect **messages** and **subscribes** controllers back to tabs after sign in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a baseViewController, make all three viewController's extend that base.
2. Think of a method that will show the user "please sign-in" message. A gray UIView (with a UILabel and two UIButtons) overriding all the content seems good to me.
3. Add the buttons on that gray UIView, with self s as targets
4. Check in the viewWillAppear method whether the user is not logged in or not. Show the gray view if not.

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean and before you fire the segue you proof, if the boolean is yes or no. When the boolean is yes, the segue is performed. Otherwise a segue to your Login View is performed.

I hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

to do this

```
@interface Messages
{
    BOOL loggedIn;
    UILabel *pleaseSignIn;
    UIButton *signin;
    UIButton *register;
}


- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{


    if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"logged"] isEqualToString:@"YES"])
    {

        loggedIn = YES;
    }

    else
    {
         loggedIn = NO;
    }
    if(loggedIn)
    {
         //Display messages
        pleaseSignin.hidden = YES;
        signin.hidden = YES;
        register.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        //Remove messages view
        pleaseSignin.hidden = NO;
        signin.hidden = NO;
        register.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```